# RDD Save as Text file

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, rdd

How can i save a text file with a delimited format using the RDD.save as Text file?.. Also i need to write the dataframe columns as headers.. How do i achieve that?

Is there a easier way than below for large RDDs..

```
List<Row> data = resultFrame.toJavaRDD().collect();
    try {
      File file = new File(fileName);

      if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
      }

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);

      BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      for (Row dataRow:data)
      {
        StringBuilder row  = new StringBuilder();
          for(int i = 0; i<dataRow.size();i++)
          {
            row.append(dataRow.get(i));
            if (i != dataRow.size()-1)
            {
              row.append("~");
            }

          }
        bufferedWriter.write(row.toString());
        bufferedWriter.write("\n");
        row.setLength(0);
      }
      bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error in writing to the ruf file");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. The following worked

```
public class TildaDelimiter implements Function<Row, String> {

  public String call(Row r) {
    return r.mkString("~");
  }
}

in my save as i did the following to save as a ~ delimited file

 resultFrame.toJavaRDD().map(new TildaDelimiter()).coalesce(1, true)
            .saveAsTextFile(folderName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you read using *SQLContext.read* ([Java API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#read())), you need to use *DataFrame.write* ([Java API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#write())).

The other ways are deprecated (e.g. SQLContext.parquetFile, SQLContext.jsonFile).